# How to install golang tools globally and then use them in multiple projects in different GOPATH?

Tags: go

Most of the golang tools like golint, gopkgs etc are installed like libraries with `go get` for instance, `go get -v github.com/golang/lint/golint` or `go get -v github.com/tpng/gopkgs`. I wonder why these are not just binaries that run through the source code, like `go fmt`, for example?

Since I work on multiple Go projects at the same time, I prefer having different `GOPATH` for different projects and so I am having to install these tools into every single project so that I can lint or have auto completions.

Am I doing something wrong or is there a way to install these tools globally and then just use them in multiple projects? How do people handling multiple projects manage this?

**EDIT:**

I am not asking about vendoring of libraries or about projects using different versions of Go at the same time. My question is about having to install tools like lint and gopkgs into every GOPATH, why they were designed to be treated like libraries instead of being provided as a global binary like `go fmt` which then could've been used in multiple projects, just like we use `go fmt`

Comment: You're asking too many questions at once. What do you want to know here?  Why this design decision, or how to handle multiple projects with different versions of Go?

Comment: When you've built those binaries, you can copy them wherever you want, such as $HOME/bin/ and add that to your PATH, or even copy them to /usr/bin/

Comment: @Flimzy I have edited the question to be more clear. Yes, my question is about this design decision and how people avoid having to ``go get`` the same tools especially when they have different projects in different GOPATHs. Hope I am clear.

Comment: @nos I didnt know that could be done. So if i compile say, golint and put it to usr/bin/ would editors like vscode or atom be able to use it?

Comment: @Nithin if you don't follow the conventional way of doing stuff - prepare to suffer. Battling GOPATH is much more time consuming than just having a single GOPATH as intended. The same is applied for almost everything else: if you don't follow the "go-way" it would hurt.

Comment: @zerkms I totally understand your point. But i still dont understand why a tool like a linter cant be a binary, they dont need to change the source like ``go test`` does, do they? Its just a linter after all.

Comment: Speculation on my part, but they might be external tools because they simply aren't a required part of the core of Go. I myself have never needed any of these alternate tools. Everything encompassed in the `go` command has been enough. So my speculation is that they are simply slimming the main tools down. Also, a change to the source of one of said tools would require a new Go version (kind of a big deal), and everyone's systems would update for the changes. Having them external allows for more agile development of these individual tools.

Comment: @Nithin it can be distributed as a binary. Ask your OS package manager team to bundle it for you or build a package yourself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> so I am having to install these tools into every single project so that I can lint or have auto completions.

No you don't: see how Visual Studio Code does it through its [Microsoft `vscode-go`](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-go) plugin (since its 0.6.53 version, January 2017).

> New setting `go.toolsGopath`,  for providing an alternate location to install all the Go tools that the extension depends on, if you don't want them cluttering your `GOPATH`.
> See [PR 351](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-go/pull/351) and [PR 737](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-go/pull/737)

The tools installed in that one common `` folder are:

```
'gocode': 'github.com/nsf/gocode',
'gopkgs': 'github.com/tpng/gopkgs',
'go-outline': 'github.com/ramya-rao-a/go-outline',
'go-symbols': 'github.com/acroca/go-symbols',
'guru': 'golang.org/x/tools/cmd/guru',
'gorename': 'golang.org/x/tools/cmd/gorename',
'gomodifytags': 'github.com/fatih/gomodifytags',
'impl': 'github.com/josharian/impl'
```

(and a few others, around `godoc`, `goimports` or `goreturns`, `dlv`, ...),

That means your `GOPATH` is composed of:

- your project-specific workspace folder
- a global `go.toolsGopath` workspace folder dedicated to tools used by all projects.
  The tools are installed/updated in the `bin/` subfolder of that latter workspace.

You can do that manually too (without Visual Studio Code): simply set `GOPATH` to that global tools folder whenever you want to install/update the tools.

Then reset `GOPATH` to `my/project/dedicated/workspace;/tools/workspace`, and add both `bin/` subfolders to your `$PATH`/`%PATH%`.

The [OP Nithin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1351876/nithin) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44863276/why-are-golang-tools-installed-like-libraries-and-not-as-binaries-somewhere-glob/44867509#comment76726509_44867509):

> these tools can be compiled to binaries and if those binaries are available in `$PATH`, most editors, as far as I tested (based on your post), both vscode and atom (go-plus) will work and wont `go get` them again.
>
> It is easier to update if they are treated like libraries. (I mean `go get`)

Comment: so there is no particular reason as to why golang tools installed like libraries and not as binaries somewhere global? Its just a matter of convenience?

Comment: @Nithin https://golang.org/doc/code.html#Overview: "Go programmers typically keep all their Go code in a single workspace." For that reason, libraries and tools alike are installed in the same workspace.

Comment: @Nithin My point, with this answer, is that you can have two separate workspaces for two different usages.

Comment: Can you update your answer to mention that these tools can be compiled to binaries and if those binaries are available in $PATH, most editors, as far as I tested (based on your post), both vscode and atom (go-plus) will work and wont ``go get`` them again.

As to why they are not binaries in the first place, I think it mostly comes the maintainer's  decision. I will also add that its easier to update if they are treated like libraries. (I mean ``go get``)

Comment: @Nithin Good points. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.